# Socket.io 'Cannot connect'. Client on different domain/port

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm having trouble connecting to socket.io with the client being located on a different port, on the same machine.

The client is part of a site run on Apache (port 80) and Nodejs is being run on 8585.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

On the client side, I get the 'Unable to connect Socket.IO' message, with no reason.

**Server:**

```
var express       = require('express'),
    connect       = require('connect'),
    RedisStore    = require('connect-redis')(express),
    io            = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    routes        = require('./routes'),
    request       = require('request');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: "secret", store: new RedisStore}));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, callback) {
    console.log('authorization');
    callback(null, true);
});

//Socket IO connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var session = socket.handshake.session;
    console.log(session);
});

app.listen(8585);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

**Client:** (run from a site on apache and different domain, but same server).

```
    var sio = io.connect('http://localhost:8585');

    sio.socket.on('error', function (reason){
        console.error('Unable to connect Socket.IO', reason);
    });

    sio.on('connect', function (){
        console.error('successfully established a working connection \o/');
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're running the browser on the same computer as the server, "localhost" in your code will refer to the computer running the browser, not the server. DNS lookups for localhost always resolve to the computer doing the lookup. And even if you're accessing the site on the same computer as the server, unless you're accessing it as "localhost", the browser's security policies will prevent you from talking to localhost.

Comment: Ah, ok so I changed it to the IP and like you said, in the browser I get is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  Is there something I'm missing to allow access?

Comment: @dave: There are a few options. One is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (http://enable-cors.org/). Another is just to put the two servers behind a reverse proxy like nginx to have them served from the same port (with Socket.io serving requests to some particular path, like `http://yourdomain.com/live`).

Comment: Isn't this one of the benefits of socket.io though? That it can work across origins?  I'm able to access it directly in the browser from the client machine, if I go to http://ip:8585  it works.  But socket.io doesn't seem to.

Comment: @dave: Ah, you're right, it is supposed to be able to. That is strange. Sorry, I always just used it on the same domain, so I hadn't even thought about it. Hrm.

Comment: No problem, thank you.  I did add {origins: '*'} to the socket.io .listen(app, {origins: '*'} - but still no luck.